# Google Chrome Application Shortcuts with Tabs

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am looking for a way to run a Google Chrome Application Shortcut (e.g. chrome.exe  --app=https://mail.google.com/ ) with tabs.

The reason I am using a lot of pages as Application Shortcuts is that they provide an individual link on the taskbar (like IE9's "pinned sites") in Windows 7. I don't want to un-pin my "run of the mill" Chrome browsing sessions (though it would be nice to split Incognito and non-Incognito windows).

If these individual apps could open additional tabs (e.g. if you could open Google Docs, and *then* your individual spreadsheets in new tabs) we'd be in business.

I'd use IE9's pinned sites but it doesn't support desktop notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Save the regular page ( with tabs)  to your Bookmarks bar- then drag it to your desktop- that short cut opens the regular  page with tabs